# The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Error launching WinPTY agent: agent died)

Tags: python-3.x

The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Error launching WinPTY agent: agent died).

How to solve this problem?

The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Error launching WinPTY agent: agent died).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.